# pip version warning in Python but terminal version is showing latest version

Tags: python, pip

I am receiving the following warning when I install a package through pip in Python:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\wildman\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

However, when I run the pip --version command in terminal, it is saying:

```
pip 22.2.2
```

Can somebody please provide some pointers on resolving this?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using the `C:\Users\wildman\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` command? You might have 2 pythons installed one on anaconda one on appdata. Try cheking for that.

Comment: I think you installed multiple python versions on your system. check the python version also.

Answer (score 0):

the warning says pip in conda environment.

C:\Users\wildman\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip

check your that pip using this command :

C:\Users\wildman\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip --version

maybe if you directly pip --version, it direct to another python environment